# PHP PCRE parse javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, regex, replace, pcre

I'm trying to parse a javascript code that generates a map, so that I can get the coordinates that it's using (the first 2 long values inside the following example).

The example :

```
new OpenLayers.LonLat(-9.2009313718432200, 38.6318891148480000), 9);
```

The function I'm using is as follows :

```
preg_replace('/LonLat\(([0-9 ,\-\.^\)]{0,})\)/i', '$1', $coords);
```

Got no success so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regex something like this:

```
preg_match('/LonLat\(([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)),\s*([+-]?\d+(\.\d+))/', $coords, $matches);
$longitude = $matches[1];
$latitude  = $matches[3];
```

My PHP is a bit rusty so YMMV. Your expression for matching a floating point number is far more convoluted that it needs to be, just a simple "optional sign followed by some digits followed by a decimal point followed by some more digits" is sufficient:

```
[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)
```

And don't forget to skip `$matches[2]` and `$matches[4]`, those will contain the inner capture groups (i.e. ".20093137..." and ".6318891..." in your example).

And don't bother with `preg_replace()` for things like this, you're just looking for things, you're not trying to change anything. You could use `preg_replace()` but then you'd have to parse the post-replacement value again to get the two pieces out.

Comment: Perfect! Just a note, the "1" and "3" keys of the matches are the ones right, not like you mentioned, at least in my PHP version. Thank you very much, Shiva bless you and merry christmas :)

Comment: @yoda: Thanks, you're right on the indices so I fixed 'em: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php, my PHP is rather rusty.